# VBA: migrate value down if combo box is selected via Userform

Tags: vba, excel

This may be sort of confusing to explain but I'll do my best. I have a spreadsheet with a userform that takes in a name and date, and four different areas where the user inputs data, the primary one being a dropdown box "heat shrunk" that says "yes" or "no". I've included a screenshot to show exactly what it looks like.

[image: Here is the userform.]

What I need is for my spreadsheet to carry down the name inputted at the top to be carried down through multiple cells when the "heat shrunk" dropdown has the value of "Yes" or "No." So that way, if the user fills out more than one of the cable type lines, the name will drop down to every entry, not just the first. The spreadsheet fills out as such:

```
    'inputting cable types to end of column D in sheet
     N1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Cells(N1, "D").Value = UserForm1.Cable1Text.Value

     N2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Cells(N2, "D").Value = UserForm1.Cable2Text.Value
```

and so on.

Thank you for any help: let me know if clarification is needed!

Comment: What happens in the worksheet now when you run this code?  We see the form but don't know what associates to Cable2TextValue, is it the cable type?  You mention name.  Also we don't know if you have more than one worksheet, you are using cells but not directly saying what worksheet or workbook is a reference.  There are several ways to do that but just using cells or any other worksheet reference without explicit reference may cause some trouble.  This is issue is very doable but need more info to help.  Also appears you want conditional action based on the heat shrunk drop down.

Comment: Right now, the inputted data just inserts into the next available row. So for this particular code, when you type in the type of cable, it inserts into the next column that hasn't been used in  a single sheet. There's only one sheet in the workbook. What I need is for the name inserted at the top to appear in column A next to all of the other things they insert: so if you type your name "Bob," that will show up in column A next to Column D where the cable type is being inserted.

Comment: At the end of your processes that you give examples for it sounds a lot like: Cells(N1, "A").Value = Userform1.whateverTheNameReferenceIsText.Value  and repeat for N2, N3, N4.  My recommendation is to name your userform and not use the Userform1 reference that it VBA gives you.  Eventually if you continue down this road, perhaps seperate the form from its functions in a M-V-P or M-V-C (older) format.  Is that all you were looking for?